# In a .NET application, is it possible to get a representation of the DOM as a web browser would see it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need for a server side process to be able to produce the same view of the HTML dom for a web page as a web browser (I am aware that the dom representation is browser specific, so don't mind a non cross browser solution).

I need to be able to work my way back to a user selection on a web page at a later date. Since there is no firm relationship between the raw HTML for a page, and the Dom that a browser constructs, this is proving very difficult to say the least!

My thinking is now that if I can produce the same view of the document in a server side process, then I may be able to achieve this.

Does anyone have experience of this?

Thanks

Comment: Why? It sounds like you might be overcomplicating things. What is the end goal? Why do you need to get some value later, and the value must be gotten to by somehow back-tracing instead of stored in session or other state bag?

Comment: "I need to be able to work my way back to a user selection on a web page at a later date."  This sounds like an audit trail requirement. If so there are far simpler ways of capturing audit trail than trying to reconstruct what a page looked like on the browser.

Comment: The data is read from external websites not under our control. Obviously I wouldn't try get information from my own website this way.

Comment: When I say selection I mean as in highlighted text on a web page. Should have made this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... for what it's worth, I was able to successfully use WebBrowser control (yeah, from System.Windows.Forms) to load remote page and iterate its DOM freely.

The bricks in the wall I faced and destroyed are below.

Full code, which for the sake of example show all images in the remote page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;

namespace TestZone
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private bool waiting = false;
        private WebBrowser browser = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadRemotePage));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            waiting = true;
            thread.Start(this);

            while (waiting)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }

        private void LoadRemotePage(object sender)
        {
            try
            {
                browser = new WebBrowser();
                browser.Tag = sender;
                browser.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082249/in-a-net-application-is-it-possible-to-get-a-representation-of-the-dom-as-a-web/4085520");
                browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
                while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                browser.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                litDebug.Text = "Error while initializing browser control: " + ex.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
                (sender as _Default).waiting = false;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            //hgcDebug.GetType().InvokeMember("InnerHtml", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, hgcDebug, new object[] { "done" });
        }

        void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                HtmlElementCollection collection = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendFormat("Total of {0} images:<br />", collection.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
                    sb.AppendFormat("name: {0}, src: {1}<br />", collection[i].GetAttribute("name"), collection[i].GetAttribute("src"));
                litDebug.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                litDebug.Text = "Error while analyzing remote page: " + ex.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
            }
            finally
            {
                ((sender as WebBrowser).Tag as _Default).waiting = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bumps along the way, if anyone is curious:

1. Exception while creating the WebBrowser control.. thread was in wrong state. Fixed by moving the code to new thread explicitly setting the ApartmentState to STA.
2. Document property of the WebBrowser was null. First step of the fix was using the DocumentCompleted event instead of tring to access the Document right after Navigating.
   Still no luck though, DocumentCompleted never occurred. To fix that I added the loop waiting until the ReadyState is complete. Done and working, but..
3. All this done, changing the literal from within the new thread had no effect on the actual GUI.. had to wait in the main thread until everything was done.

Hope this will come handy someday for someone, if not for the OP here. :)

Comment: I've got to mark this one the answer, as at the end of the day this is as close as your going to get to seeing the dom through a browsers eye view. Whether that will be similar to the view of a modern browser (ish) such as IE8, who knows. In the end I've managed to take another angle on my problem, since the approach descirbed in my question was obviously not the right one, but had I been nailed to it, this would have helped.

Comment: Cheers, glad you found better angle and glad to win the jackpot here. ;)

Answer (score 2):

OK, different angle.
What about using the [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28VS.71%29.aspx)?

As far as I know, there's nothing preventing web application from adding reference to System.Windows assembly and using it.

Bit of a long shot, but IMO worth trying!

Comment: Definiate +1 because took me ages to think of that, but I have tried it, and it's not really suitable since the application has to be distributable in a web browser.

Comment: Yup just tried it myself and hit a brick wall. But.. what about this? http://watin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Brick wall successfully broken.. for what it's worth, I'll post my fully working code as new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best you can achieve is using WebRequest to read the raw response (HTML output) of the page and assuming it's valid XHTML throw it into XmlReader and you have kind of DOM at hand, at least the nodes.

Comment: Yeah thought of that. Chances of the pages being valid xhtml is slim. Wont match browser dom either. Cheers though.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously used an HTML parsing library called [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/Community/SgmlReader), which worked well for getting HTML tag soup into a workable DOM. I would be surprised if it always produces a DOM identical to what a browser would produce though.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like a useful tool. Not sure if I can apply it here though. +1